# Running jar file with terminal command but not by double click

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jar

I am developing a javafx/sqlite application in Netbeans 8.2 named: store database manager. I am working in Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. The app has a login start screen and after that there is a table and buttons, where you can see/insert/update/delete the data from my sqlite database.

Everything is working OK when I run the app inside Netbeans. I can view, insert,delete or update data in my sqlite database.

Also, the app is running normally when I build and run the jar file with terminal command (java -jar storeDBmanager.jar).

There are no errors in the IDE log console, when I build the jar file. There are no errors in the terminal/console when i run it with terminal command.

Providing below the source code link. https://github.com/vaios84/storeDB-manager-javafx-sqlite.

The problem is that it is not working when I double click the jar file. Any thoughts why is that happening??

Any comment/advice will be helpful.

Comment: Did you check 'Allow executing file as a program' in .jar file Properties -> Permissions?

Comment: yes, I have already tried this...

Comment: BTW, I had similar problem recently with JavaFX 8. When the .jar file was doubleclicked the app started but some of its features wouldn't work. I kinda bypassed this unknown problem as I created a simple shell script which included the launch command from terminal, i.e. java -jar somefile.jar (like a batch file in windows). Although this didn't resolve the problem it allowed me to start the program without problems by doubclicking th .sh file. Thus all app features worked fine.

Comment: Just to add some more info: the app that I'm talking about worked without any problems on Windows 10.

Comment: Are you using Windows? Then maybe you're looking for [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @caco3 I think Vaios is using Ubuntu 16.04 so my comments are about this OS.

Comment: @AlexanderAgopov It's written in the question. My bad..

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers.. @AlexanderAgopov I used your idea and created .sh & .bat files for Linux and Windows, respectively.. But still can't understand why the .jar file is not responding at all when doubleclicked.. Thanks anyway!